# $\ 3\,\tan(x)-\sqrt3 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

You have to find alternate form, that has only multiplication/division signs between trigonometric functions

The form is: $\ 3\,\tan(x)-\sqrt3 $

The solution form is: $\ \left(\frac{2*\sqrt 3\sin(x-π/6)}{\cos(x)}\right) $

My try: $\ 3\,\tan(x)-\sqrt3 = 3*\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)-\left(\frac{\sin(π/3)}{\cos(π/3)}\right)= \left(\frac{\sin(x)\cos(π/3)-\sin(π/3)\cos(x)}{\cos(x)\cos(π/3)}\right)=\left(\frac{\sin(x)\cos(π/3)+\sin(x)\cos(π/3)-\sin(π/(3)\cos(x)}{\cos(x)\cos(π/3)}\right)$

I am certain that I have done something wrong in one of the steps, as this leads to only more complicated form, that isn't even near the solution

Comment: $3\tan(x)-\sqrt3$ is *not* an equation.

Comment: If you type \sin instead of sin, your trig functions will look nicer.

Comment: I apologise for the inconvinience, I will be more careful with my terminology in future posts. Thank you. And also thanks for editing my question in to a more "beautiful" form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}3\tan(x)-\sqrt3 &=& 3 (\tan x - \tan {\pi \over 6}) \\
&=& 3{\sin x \cos {\pi \over 6} - \sin {\pi \over 6} \cos x \over \cos x \cos {\pi\over 6}}\\
& = & 3{ \sin (x -{\pi \over 6})\over \cos x \cos {\pi \over 6} } \\  
& = & 2\sqrt{3}{ \sin (x -{\pi \over 6})\over \cos x  } 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I have a question in the second step, when you exposed 3, why isnt tan(π/6) multiplied with 1/3.

Comment: Because $\sqrt{3}/3 = \tan(\pi/6)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write $$3\tan x- \sqrt{3} = 2\times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\times \sqrt{3} - 2\times \sqrt{3}\times \frac{\cos x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{2}$$ $$=2\times \sqrt{3}\frac{1}{\cos x}[\sin x(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})-\cos x(\frac{1}{2})]$$ $$=\frac{2\times \sqrt{3}}{\cos x}[\sin x\cos \frac{\pi}{6}-\cos x\frac{\pi}{6}]$$ $$=\frac{2\sqrt{3}\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})}{\cos x}$$

Comment: It's very interesting how you solved this. Cheers!